# Moving a solr instance to a test server

Tags: tomcat, drupal, solr

I am currently in the process of moving a drupal site over to a test environment on another server and the site includes a Solr 3.5 installation (running with Tomcat 6 on a Cent OS server).

I've already set up the Tomcat servlet and the Drupal site on another CentOS box, but I am wondering about the Solr installation and what I need to do to bring it over. So far it is not working and I am having trouble identifying what all needs to be changed for the new environment.

On the production server, the Solr files are in the Drupal home directory, so they were brought over when I brought over the Drupal files. But what will I need to change to recognize the new server and the Tomcat servlet (which I am sure is configured just a little bit differently on the dev server in terms of where it is located etc.).

Or is it better to do a fresh Solr install and just bring over a few key files from the production server?

Comment: I'd go with a fresh install, but copy over the conf files that are active in the Drupal install (elevate.xml, mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt, protwords.txt, schema.xml and the rest that are included with whichever Drupal SOLR module you're using). Then just invoke an index-rebuild from the Drupal UI on your test version

Comment: great, that's pretty much what I needed to know. thanks.